# Meshlab volume and area measurements of a mesh

Tags: meshlab

I need help because I do not know where to start. I'm not a programmer

I work with wounds and I wanted to see for my PhD if I can, with a 3D scan, measure the area, volume and depth of a wound.

This scanner obtains both STL and OBJ. I get a mesh with the topography of the wound.

Can you guide me if in the meshlab it can be done? I know that in Artec Studio it can be done but due to access difficulty I can not use it.

Thank you very much to all.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you'd like to enclose a hole/valley (the wound) and measure the resulting volume. I expect the shapes are not simple, so what I'd suggest is to first delete the surface that is not part of the wound.

To get an immediate approximation you can use Filters->Remeshing, Simplification and Reconstruction->Convex hull which will create a volume that encloses your surface. It usually gets the face normal inconsistent (some will appear black while other will be white), so use Normals->Re-orient All Faces Coherently to fix this. Then use Quality Measure->Compute Geometric Measures.

If the containment is not satisfactory you'll have to go further and delete the faces you don't want from the hull, flatten all layers, and then fill holes to create a closer fit. To measure depth you can use the measure tape tool in the tool bar.